# Flash Remoting and Java

Tags: java, flash, remoting

I want to use Flash Remoting in my Flash app that is backed by a Java server. I'm interested in what my options are for using Flash Remoting with Java. I know about [BlazeDS](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/blazeds/BlazeDS/) but it seems to be fully geared towards Flex, not Flash (AS3). I'd like to make simple AMF calls, as like in the old days.

If I can I use BlazeDS for this and if yes, can anyone point me to a good tutorial. Otherwise, are there any other good solutions available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luke,
You can try start with this article by James Ward http://www.infoq.com/articles/blazeds-intro to make yourself intro what technologies are involved.
Also, I would like to consider ClearToolkit framework ( http://cleartoolkit.com/dokuwiki/doku.php ). This tool allow you to create crud Java+Flex applications (dao, dto, configs) in few minutes ( tutorial - workshop http://www.cleartoolkit.com/documents/CDBGettingStartedWorkshop.pdf ). It's unobstructive and can save the time in plumbing flex frontend and java+blazeDS backend.
Also, there is alternative solution for Flex remoting called GraniteDS ( http://www.graniteds.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=229378 )

Answer (score 0):

There should not be difference on server side if this is flex or pure AS3. In the latter use Netconnection class you find examples with amfphp 
Beside BlaseDs there is openamf